# How can I Increase DPI of the image file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, image, dpi

I have used Fabric.js canvas and export image using dataurl() method. It is exporting image at 96 dpi, I need it at 300 dpi.

I have base64 string of image.

What I tried:

first, I converted my base64 string of image into hex string then after replacing 13 to 17 byte of an image which contains dpi value like '01 2c 01 2c' and then again converted into base64 but it generated an invalid image.

reference link: http://www.apptools.com/examples/dpi.php

I also tried the solution from below link but it also generates the invalid image: 
https://andreyvoev.com/programming/change-the-dpi-of-a-jpeg-image-with-php/

Is it possible using javascript only?
Can anyone help me?

Comment: The DPI is metadata about the image to suggest the **physical** dimensions of the image. Very little cares about it, especially on the WWW. Do you really care?

Answer (score 0):

I think , you should try imagemagick library for conversion.

Reference Link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemagick

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: `node-imagemagick` runs on Node, not in the browser. The question is tagged [tag:php]. This module won't run in the browser. This module doesn't help.

Comment: I'm using angular and php